# SDWebImage not works with Spanish Alphabets into Image name iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage latest updated version & it works good so far. Recently I found one issue which started causing the crash issue into my Application.

I observed that if Image URL having a Alphabet in Spanish then its unable to download & generates the nil exception. This later on coverts into the crash issue.

Here how I used it :

```
    cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imString)!) { (img, error, type, url) in
        cell.imgView.image  = img?.resizeTopAlignedToFill(newWidth: collectionView.frame.size.width)
                cell.imgView.contentMode = .top
    }
```

This kind of URL where image name is having Spanish Alphabet do not works :

> [https://test.com/uploads/image_watermark/cloacacaña.PNG](https://test.com/uploads/image_watermark/cloacaca%C3%B1a.PNG)

**Important Note :**

- I have done enough research on it & found that any language which contains special alphabets which are not normal like English Alphabets causing the same issue.

Please help me out if someone has found any solution to resolve this issue.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Quick question does `URL(string: imString)` where `imString` is the URL with the tilde crashing? If yes, what about percent escaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a proper URL. Try changing your url string by adding utf encoding.

```
cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!) { (img, error, type, url) in
cell.imgView.image  = img?.resizeTopAlignedToFill(newWidth: collectionView.frame.size.width)
cell.imgView.contentMode = .top }
```

Comment: Do be careful using `addingPercentEncoding` this way. It does not always create the URL you intend. Not all parts of an URL have the same rules. You're applying the query section's rules to the whole URL. If you know all the URLs you will process, you may be able to get away with it, but this approach is a common cause of double-encoding errors (encoding things that are already encoded), and other subtle problems. For example, this approach breaks URL-fragments ("https://example.com/abc#xyz" becomes "https://example.com/abc%23xyz").

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid URL, so `URL.init` returns nil. See [RFC 3986 section 3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) that defines the legal characters for the path component:

```
  pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

The [unreserved characters](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.3) are:

```
  unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

ALPHA includes the characters A-Z and a-z (specifically it's %41-%5a and %61-%7a). `ñ` is not in that list, so it needs to be percent encoded to be in the path section. The same is true of any other letters outside US-ASCII.

(RFC 3986 covers general URIs, and individual schemes are allowed to have different rules, but http doesn't in this case. You still need to percent-encode ñ.)

The correct URL is:

```
https://test.com/uploads/image_watermark/cloacaca%C3%B1a.PNG
```

Note that lots of things (particularly web browsers) are very loose about the URLs they accept and will handle all kinds of mis-encodings. Foundation is not. It follows the spec very closely, so you need to make sure your URLs do to.

Typically the best way to create URLs dynamically is using URLComponents, which will encode each component correctly:

```
// Start with the static part that you know is correct
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://test.com")!

// Then add dynamic parts   
let file = "cloacacaña"
components.path = "/uploads/image_watermark/\(file).PNG"

print(components.url!)
// https://test.com/uploads/image_watermark/cloacaca%C3%B1a.PNG
```

You can also construct URLs directly by appending dynamic portions:

```
let file = "cloacacaña"
let url = URL(string: "https://test.com/uploads/image_watermark")!
    .appendingPathComponent(file)
    .appendingPathExtension("PNG")
// https://test.com/uploads/image_watermark/cloacaca%C3%B1a.PNG
```

URLComponents is much more flexible, however, since it can handle encoding all the parts of the URL (host, fragment, query, etc.), which have different rules. URL can only handle encoding path components.

Comment: than in that case why the same URL working well on Android side ?

Comment: Because Android translates it for the user? As said by Rob Napier, `Note that lots of things (particularly web browsers) are very loose about the URLs they accept and will handle all kinds of mis-encodings. Foundation is not`, `Foundation` being `Foundation.framework`, the "Base framework".

Comment: Thank you @Rob Larme I found the solution finally